# Retreive the list of Up/Down status of Oracle database using Shell Script

Tags: bash, oracle

I am trying to create a shell script for retrieving the list of Oracle database with status UP/DOWN.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please show us what you have tried, and where you are stuck.

Comment: The answer depends on how you know what databases are supposed to be running. If you have RAC, then the answer is easier and you can use the command `crsctl status resource -t` to get a list of statuses, and build a shell script to parse that output.

Answer (score 0):

Are all the databases running on one server?  If so, start with

```
/home/mark > ps -fu oracle | grep pmon
oracle   15060     1  0  2019 ?        00:28:00 ora_pmon_test01
oracle   53410     1  0 Jan08 ?        00:15:33 ora_pmon_rcatn
```

And if that output matches what seems reasonable, pipe it through `cut`:

```
/home/mark > ps -fu oracle | grep pmon | cut -d_ -f3
test01
rcatn
```

But that really doesn't verify if the database is fully up and running; you'll likely need something like Jon mentioned in his comments.  And anything beyond what I listed above, gets complex quickly.
The PMON process is (to oversymplify) the main watchdog of an Oracle database, so if a PMON process is running, the database *might* be available and online.  99.9% of the time, yes, but you want to also know if it is accessible.